# VBA array of array

Tags: arrays, vba

I've got a 3-dimensional array, call it Arr(25,10,10), where I want to copy all contents of a given first index to another first index, e.g. Arr(6,-,-) to Arr(17,-,-). I'd like to do this without using For..Next loops every time. I think what I need is to change the array structure so it becomes a 1-dimensional array (Arr(25)) having a 2-dimensional array (Arr2(10,10)) as its elements, but I'm not sure how to do that. How do I Dim the array and how do I copy one index to another?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a loop?  VBA doesn't have a lot of useful array-oriented methods, so a loop is often the "best" way to get something done without involving (eg) worksheet functions (which have terrible performance when used in for VBA arrays vs. against a worksheet)

Comment: @Tim Williams Well, it just seems very inefficient. I need to do this procedure perhaps millions of times. Isn't it much faster to set one array equal to another rather than populating the array with For..Next loops?

Comment: Maybe yes, if there were some built-in way to do that.  Array loops are pretty fast, so "inefficient" isn't really a problem here.  However, there's no problem having an array of arrays in VBA - you can arrange them as nested as you need.

Comment: @Tim Williams Could you show me how to Dim such an array and how to copy one element to another? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restructure your array you can do something like this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr(25)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 25
        Dim a(10, 10)
        arr(i) = a
    Next i

    arr(6)(1, 1) = 99
    arr(17)(1, 1) = 88

    arr(17) = arr(6)

    Debug.Print arr(17)(1, 1) '>> 99

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses a Type to define the two-D array, and then packs it within the 1-D array

```
Option Explicit

Type Ta2D
    a2D(1 To 10, 1 To 10)
End Type


Sub ArraySlicing_take3()


    Dim a1D(1 To 25) As Ta2D

    'Populate a sample 3-D array with values...
    Dim x, y, z
    For z = 1 To 25
    For y = 1 To 10
    For x = 1 To 10
        a1D(z).a2D(y, x) = "D" & z & "R" & y & ":C" & x
    Next x
    Next y
    Next z
    '...done setting up sample array

    Dim w(1) As Ta2D
    w(1) = a1D(6)
    a1D(17) = w(1)

End Sub
```

'